# How does PowerBuilder handle sql server connection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, powerbuilder

In PowerBuilder you dont have to send connstring at any sql CRUD, so how does he do that?

and is it good to be in .NET send sql connstring beside any SQLCommand(CRUD, conn)

hope to know

Comment: Are you referring to PowerBuilder the language, or the IDE?

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11295053/19072 to another question might help you

Comment: I mean PowerBuilder codeing, and when use Datawindows you dont send any connstring to update data

Answer (score 0):

Connection strings are passed in sqlca.DBParm when you execute CONNECT. When you call the Update function on a DataWindow, it sends the UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT SQL statements to the database automatically.

Have you even used PowerBuilder before? This is pretty basic stuff.

In the future, please specify PowerBuilder version and whether you are using PowerBuilder .Net or Classic.

Comment: Good, but in .Net in every action send connection and command
but PowerBuilder handle connection pool and just send command(update, delete, insert .. etc)
so how does PowerBuilder do that ?

Comment: When you call the Update method of the DataWindow control, it generates the update/insert/delete statements automatically and sends them to the database on the existing connection. That is why PowerBuilder is easier and faster to code in than other languages.